# Validating Mongo Cursor in Meteor Template

Tags: mongodb, meteor, cursor

The code below shows how to validate a Mongo.Cursor. My Question is, why would someone want to validate a Mongo.cursor. It's a bit abstract for me. I mean if I manipulate data and click on a button, I understand the reason for validation, but on a Mongo.Cursor?

```
Template.Lists_show.onCreated(function listShowOnCreated() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    new SimpleSchema({
     list: { type: Function },
      todosReady: { type: Boolean },
      todos: { type: Mongo.Cursor },
    }).validate(Template.currentData());
  });
```

Comment: Why do you want to validate a Mongo Cursor?

Comment: Simple. If you expect a data argument to be a Cursor and you will call Cursor methods on it, you want to make sure it is a Cursor